# JTree and JEditorPane in Java

Tags: java, html, swing, jtree, jeditorpane

I have JTree and JEditorPane control in a Swing form . JTree has 3 nodes and further subnodes . I have to set text in front of the nodes and subnodes eg following

```
delhi :100
old delhi:50
new delhi:50
mumbai:200
.....
```

these 50 100 and 200  value should be set run time.
On clicking on node on delhi or old delhi the table values should be changed and while clicking on a cell in JTable the value of JEditorPane should be changed with the corresponding Html file

Comment: What have you done so far? Currently, it is difficult to isolate a single development question you need answering. Please share the code you have so far, preferably as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that we can copy/paste/compile and see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are talking about a JTable, a JTree... which one is it? Also what is your model behing all this? Where do you get the information displayed?

Answer (score 2):

I see there JTree and you wrote about selection in JTable, never mind, have look at

- [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)
- [JTree tutoria](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select)l
- add `TreeSelectionListener` for `JTree` and/or `ListSelectionListener` for `JTable`
- from `TreeSelectionListener` / `ListSelectionListener` event to invoke proper `Html` formated `Object` to the `JEditorPane`

notice

- all updates to the [`Swing GUI` must be done on `EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: i have created the jtree in netbeans design mode and now i want when i run the program 100 ,50 or 200 should come along with the node and subnode in jtree

Comment: @adeshkumar: The cited tutorials do not use NetBeans design mode. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.